# How to check for a substring in a column, using CASE /IF (SQL querying)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I need to return one of 2 values for certain conditions:
 My different cases are:
 when one column has 'substring' on the right end, return that column. (i.e. LIKE '%substring')
 Else return other column (from other table)

This works:

```
SELECT * From Table1 where col1 is not null and col1 like '%substring'
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
SELECT col5,
CASE Table1.Col1 
   WHEN NULL Then Table2.Col2
   WHEN '%substring' THEN Table1.Col1
   ELSE Table2.Col2
 FROM Table1
 JOIN Tablex ON Tablex.colID= Tabley.colID
 JOIN Table1 ON Table1.colID = Tablex.colID
```

and a  bunch of more joins for interrelated tables with foreign keys with table1/table2...
The results are always returned from the 'else' part.

I also tried this, this didn't work either:

```
SELECT col5,
CASE Table1.Col1 
   WHEN NULL Then Table2.Col2
   WHEN '' THEN Table2.Col2
   ELSE Table1.col1
 FROM Table1
 JOIN Tablex ON Tablex.colID= Tabley.colID
 JOIN Table1 ON Table1.colID = Tablex.colID
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Need to use:

```
SELECT col5,
       CASE 
         WHEN Table1.Col1 IS NULL Then Table2.Col2
         WHEN Table1.Col1 LIKE '%substring' THEN Table1.Col1
         ELSE Table2.Col2
       END
FROM Table1
JOIN Tablex ON Tablex.colID= Tabley.colID
JOIN Table1 ON Table1.colID = Tablex.colID
```

CASE/WHEN expressions are equivalent to "=", so specifying NULL will never evaluate properly because you need to use `IS NULL`.  Similarly, can't assume LIKE is being used...

You were also missing the `END` keyword to signal the end of the CASE expression.

Mind that `Table2.Col2` and `Table1.Col1` data types are the same too.